# spring-data-geode and spring-boot-starter-webflux application run failed

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-data-gemfire

I have a webflux project and I am adding apache geode. In my build.gradle I have:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-geode:2.2.4.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.2.4.RELEASE'
```

Once adding the spring-data-geode implementation the application crashes with:

```
2020-01-28T16:29:51,965 INFO  [main] org.eclip.jetty.util.log.Log 169 initialized: Logging initialized @4337ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2020-01-28T16:29:52,050 WARN  [main] org.sprin.conte.suppo.AbstractApplicationContext 558 refresh: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start reactive web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletHolder
2020-01-28T16:29:52,064 INFO  [main] org.sprin.boot.autoc.loggi.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener 136 logMessage: 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-01-28T16:29:52,072 ERROR [main] org.sprin.boot.SpringApplication 826 reportFailure: Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start reactive web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletHolder
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
```

The trouble is, if I add

`spring.main.web-application-type=none` or `spring.main.web-application-type=reactive` to my `application.properties` then that interferes with the `@ClientCacheApplication(name = "Web", locators = @Locator(host="1.2.3.4", port=10334), logLevel = "debug", subscriptionEnabled = true)` annotation and the application does not connect to the geode locator, nor then run the `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` which causes problems defining simple regions that I want to pick up from the server.

**UPDATE** To add `spring-boot-starter-web` to `build.gradle` and make the spring boot application type NONE as below appears to fix the instant problem, but...

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Web.class);
app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
SpringApplication.run(Web.class, args);
```

... but then the webflux mapping cannot find the `@Bean` websocket handler:

```
2020-01-28T16:54:26,236 DEBUG [http-nio-8082-exec-2] org.sprin.web.servl.handl.AbstractHandlerMapping 412 getHandler: Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-01-28T16:54:26,246 DEBUG [http-nio-8082-exec-2] org.sprin.web.servl.resou.ResourceHttpRequestHandler 454 handleRequest: Resource not found
2020-01-28T16:54:26,246 DEBUG [http-nio-8082-exec-2] org.sprin.web.servl.FrameworkServlet 1131 logResult: Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

and this causes the website to error:

[image]

The console log says

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8082/ws/data' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

Answer (score 0):

The problems with regions was because the classes using the regions defined by `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` were (a) instantiated by `new` command rather than Spring `@Autowired`; and (b) in another package not seen by the Spring Boot `@ComponentScan`. Once these were fixed then the regions were auto-defined and handled using `@Resource` annotation.

`@Resource(name = "Example") private Region<Object, Object> example`

Also the `main` program was given

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Web.class);
app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE);
SpringApplication.run(Web.class, args);
```

The other problem was fixed by getting the correct dependencies in the `build.gradle` and then annotating endpoints for rSocket / webSocket with:

```
@MessageMapping(value = "helloWorld")
public Flux<String> getFluxSocket() {
    log.traceEntry();
    log.info("In hello world");

    return Flux.just("{\"Hello\":\"World\"}");
}
```

or

```
@GetMapping(value = "/helloWorld", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> getRestSocket() {
    log.traceEntry();   
    return Flux.just("Hello World");
}
```

for HTTP endpoints.